# checking triggers in sql file

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have sql file which contains triggers. I have some 30-40 triggers in that file.
Each trigger contains the insert statement into update_delete table.
Sometimes its

```
 insert into update_delete(id,value,name)  values (:old.id,:old.value,:old.name);
```

or

```
 insert into update_delete(id,value,name)values(:old.id,:old.value,null);
```

or

```
insert into update_delete(id,name)values(:old.id,:old.name);
```

I want to write a script which scans all the triggers in sql file and check the if name field in update_delete table is inserted with old.name or null.
Please do suggest how do I proceed with this.

Comment: Maybe use a regular expression to capture the contents in parenthesis. Split them into two arrays, see which position `name` has in the first and take the element at the same position from the second. See if it's `null` or `old.name`.

Comment: Though, those statements are invalid; shouldn't the *old* and *new* values be preceded by a colon, i.e. `values (:old.id, :old.value)`?

Comment: @Littlefoot yes , it should preceed with :

Comment: This looks like a task for shell script / perl script rather than sql/oracle, because basically you want to edit a file. Try to come up with a unix command like `sed` / `awk` to achieve this. Post a question under those tags when you face issues.